# Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js with Angular 2 project

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I've just created an angular 2 project via angular-cli. Then I added `Bootstrap v4` using command `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2` provided by Bootstrap official site.

Anyway, everything works except for the following error in console window :

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)
    at scripts.bundle.js:179
    at scripts.bundle.js:588
```

I've installed `popper.js` and added inside `.angular-cli.json` :

```
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
    "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js", 
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",              
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
```

But still the error is there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've almost solved the problem using package `npm install ngx-bootstrap --save`.

Of course it's not the direct way, Nevertheless it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

Try running:

`npm install --save bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6`